# Screen Scraping

Tags: curl

now i learn cURL , i face one difficult that is to login into a page by username and password directly

Answer (score 1):

For standard HTTP authentication, you could try:

```
curl http://username:password@url
```

It should work!

Answer (score 1):

The method you need to use will depend on exactly how the web page's username/password checking is implemented, but this might help you:
http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2008-05/0113.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to fetch pages hidden behind a login page, and this page is not CAPTCHA-protected. To do it, you have to

1. send POST request with login form data to the submit URL of the login form (see HTML source)
2. save cookies
3. send these cookies with all subsequent requests (update if necessary)

I do it with `wget`. `curl` should be similar (see its manual).

1, 2:

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies "mycookies" \
     --post-data "login=mylogin&password=mypass" submit_URL
```

3:

```
wget --load-cookies "mycookies" --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies "mycookies" \
     another_URL_behind_login_form
```

From what I see in the `man curl`, 1–2 should be something like this (not tested):

```
curl -F "login=mylogin;password=mypass" -c "mycookies" submit_URL
```

and 3:

```
curl -b "mycookies" -c "mycookies" another_URL
```

But I didn't try it with `curl`.